# Can I write the output of jasmine-spec-reporter to file?

Tags: javascript, automation, protractor, jasmine-spec-reporter

I am currently using jasmine-spec-reporter to create a spec report for my Protractor test cases.

The output on the terminal looks great! Is there any way to save this output to file or somehow use protractor-jasmine2-screenshot-reporter to create a summary, but disable the screenshots?

I have tried looking online for solutions, but so far haven't been successful.

```
var SpecReporter = require('jasmine-spec-reporter');
jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new SpecReporter({displayStacktrace: 'none'}));
```

https://github.com/jintoppy/protractor-html-screenshot-reporter

https://github.com/bcaudan/jasmine-spec-reporter

My current workaround is to use the protractor-jasmine2-screenshot-reporter to generate the report. This also generates screenshots (not very practical due to the volume being created).

If anyone has a solution to disabling the screenshots, or even not allowing the .png files to save, please share.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The output on the terminal looks great! Is there any way to save this output to file

This package is what you want https://www.npmjs.com/package/jasmine-reporters. It contains several different reporting options. If you want to parse the xml into an html file you can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/jasmine-xml2html-converter

Comment: Is there an option to generate HTML files, without the stack traces? (I only see XML).  I have implemented this, but it produces reports with full stack traces.

Comment: Not sure about excluding the stack trace but I edited answer to reflect your question about HTML

Comment: This also generates screenshots (not very practical due to the volume being created).    In the screenshot reporter are you using this flag? captureOnlyFailedSpecs: true

Comment: Thanks @KCaradonna, I am only generating them on Failures, but there is over 1000 tests in different specs, and lots of false negatives are generated.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that this guy had the same need: https://github.com/Kenzitron/protractor-jasmine2-html-reporter

You can turn off screenshot if needed:

```
jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new Jasmine2HtmlReporter({
   takeScreenshots: false
}));
```